# create a time based UUID in mysql and apply partition over the table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to generate a time based UUID in mysql over one of the table, for which i can use UUID version(which is combination of timestamp + mac address of the node).

As the table is very big ,I need to partitioned the data based on that time based UUID column and the limitation is that I need to apply the partition over the time based UUID column based on year and month available in that time based uuid column value.

Based on the inputs provided ,have created the user_defined function as:

SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
delimiter $$

```
create function findObject(col_name VARCHAR(100)) returns DATETIME
begin
    DECLARE result DATETIME;
    SELECT   
       CONVERT(from_unixtime(
          (conv(                      
            concat(                   -- step 1: reconstruct hexadecimal timestamp
              substring(col_name, 16, 3)
            , substring(col_name, 10, 4)
            , substring(col_name, 1, 8)
            ), 16, 10)                -- step 2: convert hexadecimal to decimal
            div 10 div 1000 div 1000  -- step 3: go from nanoseconds to seconds
          ) - (141427 * 24 * 60 * 60) -- step 4: substract timestamp offset (October 15,  
        ),DATETIME)                          AS uuid_to_timestamp
    INTO result;
    RETURN result;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

and now using the function to partition my data :

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable2` (
  `post_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `viewid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_id` DATETIME  NULL
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE (YEAR(findObject(url_id)))  (
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2001),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

But getting the error as Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed .

Please please help me

Comment: UUID() output generated by MySQL is datetime-based already. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

Comment: yes @Akina,i need to create the partition :

PARTITION BY RANGE (extract(year_month from `UUID`))
(PARTITION P0 VALUES LESS THAN (202012) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (202104) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P2 VALUES LESS THAN (202108) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P3 VALUES LESS THAN (202112) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION P4 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB)

Is this possible?

Comment: *`(extract(year_month from UUID))`* You cannot extract the date from UUID by this way. Read according RFC then create an expression which masks needed UUID part, and use it for partitioning.

Comment: yes that is what I am looking for ,struggling since 8 days to extract the date portion from UUID however still no success

Comment: The format of UUID is well-described: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: i have managed to extract the date part from mysql but now getting  Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed near